# jQuery select all checkboxes not working when using prop or attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check all the checkboxes in a form with `jQuery` but it is not working. I have binded it to some link elements with the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#discounts_all').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').prop('checked', true);
    });

    $('#discounts_none').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').prop('checked', false);
    });

}
```

I also tried with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#discounts_all').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').attr('checked', true);
    });

    $('#discounts_none').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').attr('checked', false);
    });

}
```

The html for the elements:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="discounts_all">All</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="discounts_none">None</a>
```

However when I click them nothing happens, no errors or anything.

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE with your HTML and JS.

Comment: Probably want to throw a `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` in there somewhere or else it's probably refreshing your page

Comment: @tymeJV You mean inside the click function?

Comment: You probable have something silly wrong, like your checkboxes don't have the appropriate class: http://jsfiddle.net/RUfDS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least a major problem is that you miss the closing bracket of `ready` handler: `);` (see the comment).

---

Also instead of `javascript:void(0)` I would use `return false;`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#discounts_all').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').prop('checked', true);
        return false;
    });

    $('#discounts_none').click(function() {
        $('.discount_select').prop('checked', false);
        return false;
    });

}); // <<< Also you miss this: ");"
```

And the html:

```
<a href="#" id="discounts_all">All</a>
<a href="#" id="discounts_none">None</a>
```

[**JSDIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQKNH/)

Comment: Haha..... such a silly error the missing parentheses. Oh well, have updated the code as you suggested and it all works :)

Comment: @Brett :-) The programmers find very hard the typos. But it should throw error. ;-)